# RevTex 4.1 AIP Bibliography Formatting

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, revtex

This is my first question on TeX.SX. I am currently using the [ShareLatex AIP](https://www.sharelatex.com/) template to produce a journal article.

I have modified and customized some elements of this project's main TeX file and class file. There are a few files in the project, including the BibTex file. My main problems lie within the bibliography and citation sections. I want to obtain a bibliography in-text citation numerically with a superscript and square brackets also, so in other words, a square bracket superscript numerical citation, like [3](http://pastebin.com/PAHx5nkf), but in superscript. How would I achieve this?

Furthermore, I want to completely modify the reference section. I do not like the formatting at all. I would like to get rid of the quotes that surround every title.

Instead of this:

A.  Gusnanto,  H.  Wood,  Y.  Pawitan,  P.  Rabbitts, and S. Berri, "Correcting for cancer genome size and tumourcell content enables better estimation of copy number alterations from next-generation sequence data," Phys. Rev.28, 262 (2012).

I want it to look like this:

Gusnanto, A., Wood, H., Pawitan, Y., Rabbitts, P., and Berri, S. Correcting for cancer genome size and tumourcell content enables better estimation of copy number alterations from next-generation sequence data. *Phys. Rev*. **28**, 262 (2012).

I am attaching a MWE for the project.

I am completely new to LaTex. Please excuse my lack of knowledge or ignorance, for I am only a high school junior.

Also my MWE has some formatting errors (namely with the new column starting in the reference section)

This is my [aipsamp.bib](http://pastebin.com/V0mrxx2q)

This is my [aipsamp.tex](http://pastebin.com/PAHx5nkf)

This is [revtex4-1.cls](http://pastebin.com/rhzHVuQy)

Thanks for any help! Believe me, I have already spent 6 grueling unproductive hours trying to make it work, so ANY help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I've converted the various inactive links into active hyperlinks.

Comment: I couldn't tell if you've loaded the tex template that loads the `natbib` package. If you did, you could get superscripted citation numbers (plain, not encased in square brackets) by supplying the option `[super]` when loading the package. To get a bibliography style that's a quite close (but not perfectly so) to the style you wish to get, consider issuing the command `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`.

Comment: Thanks Mico, I was always able to get the superscript (without square brackets, and for my purposes, I don't think it is necessary to include square brackets in the citation). However, when I look at the bibliography the number is in superscript there also. That's fine, but is there anyway to change its size? The second problem I stated in my original question I think I will be able to solve by creating my own .bst file. Thanks!